# How to compare two List content data and return mismatch value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have two List. Which content simple string values. As example:

IList1 content:

- The Avengers
- Shutter Island
- Inception
- The Dark Knight Rises

List2 content:

- The Avengers
- Shutter Island
- Inception
- The Dark Knight Rises
- Parks and Recreation
- Scandal

I want to compare two list and it will return mismatch value. Like in this case it will return "Parks and Recreation" and "Scandal" as they are not matching with the values of List1.

I tried it. But it throws exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        list1.Add("The Avengers");
        list1.Add("Shutter Island");
        list1.Add("Inception");
        list1.Add("The Dark Knight Rises");

        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
        list2.Add("The Avengers");
        list2.Add("Shutter Island");
        list2.Add("Inception");
        list2.Add("The Dark Knight Rises");
        list2.Add("Parks and Recreation");
        list2.Add("Scandal");    

       try
        {
            List<string> difference = Comparator(list1, list2);
            foreach (var value in difference)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);    
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static List<string> Comparator(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery = list1.Except(list2);
        List<string> differ = null;

        foreach (string s in differenceQuery)
            differ.Add(s);

        return differ;
    }
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `List<string> differ = new List<string>();`

Comment: Inside the Comparator method, change List<string> differ = null; for List<string> differ = new List<string>();

Comment: `List<string> differ = null;` // here is your error come from.

Comment: Is the order, or number of occurrences, of the elements relevant to the desired result?

Comment: List<string> differ = new List<string>();

Comment: I would suggest reading up on how to debug code and how to use your IDE.  This is about as simple as it gets when trying to track down an error.  Any debugger will give you the line number where the error is occurring and you already know the type of the exception, so figuring out what the problem is should be straight forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
List<string> differ = null;
```

After that you try to add something to the list, but the list is `null`. There's your exception.

You could change it as follows:

```
List<string> differ = new List<string>();
```

But easier is to replace this line:

```
List<string> difference = Comparator(list1, list2);
```

By:

```
List<string> difference = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

`Except` method does exactly what you described, so just call `ToList` to get results in a `List<T>`:

```
return list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

Your code throws `NullReffereceException` because`differ` variable is not initialized:

```
    List<string> differ = null;
```

change it to:

```
    List<string> differ = new List<string>();
```

However, I would suggest using `ToList()`. You`Comparator` method won't be necessary than:

```
        List<string> difference = list2.Except(list1).ToList()
        foreach (var value in difference)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

***Update** - whole code, working as expected*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
    list1.Add("The Avengers");
    list1.Add("Shutter Island");
    list1.Add("Inception");
    list1.Add("The Dark Knight Rises");

    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    list2.Add("The Avengers");
    list2.Add("Shutter Island");
    list2.Add("Inception");
    list2.Add("The Dark Knight Rises");
    list2.Add("Parks and Recreation");
    list2.Add("Scandal");

    List<string> difference = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
    foreach (var value in difference)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

*Result*

```
Parks and Recreation
Scandal
```

Comment: But, it does not work in my case. Throws exception. What I am missing here?

Comment: So your error is somewhere else. I've posted whole method code, and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcinJuraszek. It works fine. I missed this line List<string> difference = list2.Except(list1).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Use `Except`

```
var difference = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: He is already using except.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right here.

```
List<string> differ = null;
```

Needs to be

```
List<string> differ = new List<string>();
```